# recreating sparse matrix columns for ML model predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have been working on a model using sklearn and a big part of it utilizes the `CountVectorizer()` function to create a sparse matrix from a set of strings in the training set.

ex:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=3000)
sparse_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
```

After exporting the model, whats the best way to format the data I would like to create a prediction on to match the feature names created by the training? Should I be exporting (via pickle?) `vectorizer.get_feature_names()` as well and then use that? Or is there a better way?

In other words, if in my training set `vectorizer.get_feature_names() = ['apple', 'dog', 'cat']` and I would like to make a prediction on `'hello cat'`, what should my method for feature extraction on the prediction request be? Correct me if Im wrong, but result of the feature extraction would need to be `[0, 0, 1]` to match the model.

I could also be totally off on my approach here as well, so any help or suggestions are appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you type

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=3000)
sparse_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
```

This `vectorizer` is used to fit the VOCABULARY of words that you have in `corpus`

so, use the SAME `vectorizer` to `transform` another dataset and you will see the frequency of words of your new dataset CORRESPONDING to the vocabulary of `corpus`

Remember you perform `fit_transform(X)` to say "Use the vocabulary of `X`", and you do that just once. And then you do JUST `tranform(Y)` as a way of saying, "Whatever you used for X, use them as columns, and fit the terms in `Y` into these `X` columns

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = ['love dogs, hate cows, and also pigs, actually dogs too']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=3000)
sparse_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
df = pd.DataFrame(sparse_matrix.toarray())
df.columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print(df)
```

Would give you this:

```
   actually  also  and  cows  dogs  hate  love  pigs  too
0         1     1    1     1     2     1     1     1    1
```

and then:

```
test = vectorizer.transform(['hello cat']) #Notice how I use transform and not fit_transform
df = pd.DataFrame(test.toarray())
df.columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print(df)

   actually  also  and  cat  cows  dogs  hate  love  pigs  too
0         0     0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0    0
```

Notice how `hello cat` was fit on the vocabulary of terms that `fit_transform` was called on. So in your feature extraction, you FIT your 'hello cat' to the vocabulary you called `fit_transform` on!

And now, USE ALL THESE 10 columns as FEATURES to predict a label `y`. What you are doing is called a Vector Space Model

Comment: Thank you for your help. That does help my understanding. However, say I have two files - train.py and predict.py (obviously to train the model, and then to create predictions on an input). Currently my `vectorizer` variable would be defined in train.py by the training set and therefore not by default have access to it in predict.py. If I want to keep my training and predictions separate, whats the best way to share `vectorizer` so I can perform the transform on data used as an input in predict.py?

Comment: You HAVE to do `vectorizer.transform` on on the `predict` dataset. "Hey ML model. Take a look at these 8 columns. FIND ME THE PATTERNS/PARAMETERS FOR THE BEST ACCURACY!", and so the model trains on the training set. After training, you then say "NOW THAT YOU'VE TRAINED, TELL ME HOW YOU FIT ON THIS TEST SET!" If you fit on test set with different columns.. then.. well.. your model is trained on 8 columns.. how do you expect it to understand this new test set that doesn't have 8 columns? REMEMBER! FEATURE EXTRACTION/ENGINEERING is different from model training!

Comment: Right, thats why Im asking if exporting `vectorizer.get_feature_names()` as a pickle file to be loaded by predict.py is the best method to do just that.

Comment: Ahh I see. You export the "vectorizer" as a whole. The whole thing. Not "vectorizer.get_feature_names" which would will export the vocabulary. dump(vectorizer) not dump(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

Comment: @wannabe if you liked my answer, feel free to up vote and accept